# WooCommerce - When an attribute is programmatically updated, it does not show in front end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I try to programmatically update a woocommerce product attribute, it does get updated in the database and show in the backend, but does not show in the front-end on the webpage, the code is as follows:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'Thu 22 Mar 2018 | Fri 24 Mar 2018', 'Date', false );
$product_attributes['delivery-pickup-date'] = array(
        'name' => 'Date',
        'value' => 'Thu 22 Mar 2018 | Fri 24 Mar 2018',
        'position' => 1,
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy' => 0
);

update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
WC_Product_Variable::sync($product_id);
```

I don't have any clue where I am going wrong ? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am able to fix it myself, there is an error in the code, I need to replace the following code:

```
$product_attributes['delivery-pickup-date'] = array(
    'name' => 'Date',
    'value' => 'Thu 22 Mar 2018 | Fri 24 Mar 2018',
    'position' => 1,
    'is_visible' => 1,
    'is_variation' => 1,
    'is_taxonomy' => 0
```

);

with this:

```
$product_attributes['date'] = array(
    'name' => 'Date',
    'value' => 'Thu 22 Mar 2018 | Fri 24 Mar 2018',
    'position' => 1,
    'is_visible' => 1,
    'is_variation' => 1,
    'is_taxonomy' => 0
```

);

I mean replace the key of the array ‘delivery-pickup-date’ with ‘date’ which fixed the issue in my case.